# How can JobService() to stop itself?

Tags: android

I know there is a fun `stopSelf()` in Service class to stop itself, is there a same fun to do that in `JobService()`?

**Code**

```
class RestoreService : JobService() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        logError("OnCreate")
        super.onCreate()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        logError("OnDestory")
        super.onDestroy()
    }

    override fun onStartJob(params: JobParameters): Boolean {
        Thread(Runnable { completeRestore(params) }).start()
        return true
    }

    override fun onStopJob(params: JobParameters): Boolean {
        logError("OnStop")
        return false
    }


    private fun completeRestore(parameters: JobParameters) {
        logError("Starting OK")              

        if (condition){
           //stopself()
        }       

        doSomting()

        jobFinished(parameters, false)
    }

}
```

**Added:**

```
private fun completeRestore(parameters: JobParameters) {
        logError("Starting OK")              

        if (condition){
           jobFinished(parameters, false) //Stop 
        }  else{     
            doSomting()
           jobFinished(parameters, false)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There are two ways to "stop the JobService":**

1. Return `false` from `onStartJob` which indicates job is already finished and system will release the wakelock.
2. If `onStartJob` returns `true`, service will continue running, using a separate thread when appropriate. The `JobService` will be active until `jobFinished(parameters, false)` is called. Calling `jobFinished(parameters, false)` will inform the `JobScheduler` that the job has finished its work. When the system receives this message, it releases the wakelock being held for the job.

Comment: Thanks, what you mean is just like the "Added" section in my modified question, right?

Comment: What If I want to stop the JobService from another class, I tried to create a static method in my JobService class and call for the jobFinished(), but it says I can't use non-static method from static method.